# Case-When select line issues within the group by clause

Tags: sql, group-by, syntax-error

need support, I got following error message when running my sql code,

"Line 222
Incorrect syntax near 'n/a'."

This refers to following select line, which I need to use also in the group by clause, as I got a sum aggregate function in my select line.

Line 222
Incorrect syntax near 'n/a'.

```
Select
CASE 
WHEN OH.CreditOverride = 1 THEN 'n/a'

WHEN OH.OrderHeld = 1 AND C.CreditHold = 0 AND C.AgingCreditHold = 0 AND OH.CreditOverride = 0 THEN 'HeldOrder'

WHEN C.CreditHold = 1 AND OH.OrderHeld = 0 AND C.AgingCreditHold = 0 AND OH.CreditOverride = 0 THEN 'CrHold'

WHEN C.AgingCreditHold = 1 AND C.CreditHold = 0 AND OH.OrderHeld = 0 AND OH.CreditOverride = 0 THEN 'AgingHold'

WHEN OH.OrderHeld = 1 AND C.CreditHold = 1 AND C.AgingCreditHold = 0 AND OH.CreditOverride = 0 THEN 'HeldOrder_CrHold'

WHEN OH.OrderHeld = 1 AND C.CreditHold = 0 AND C.AgingCreditHold = 1 AND OH.CreditOverride = 0 THEN 'HeldOrder_AgingHold'

WHEN C.CreditHold = 1 AND OH.OrderHeld = 0 AND C.AgingCreditHold = 1 AND OH.CreditOverride = 0 THEN 'CrHold_AgingHold'

ELSE 'n/a'
END AS HeldReason,

SUM(Case when P.PartsPerContainer <> 0 then FLOOR(OD.OrderQty / P.PartsPerContainer) else 0 end) AS [Number of Pallets to pick],

SUM(Case when P.PartsPerContainer <> 0 then (OD.OrderQty % p.PartsPerContainer) else 0 end) AS [Number of cases to Picks] ,

SUM(Case when P.PartsPerContainer <> 0 then FLOOR(OD.OrderQty / p.PartsPerContainer) + (OD.OrderQty % p.PartsPerContainer) else 0 end) AS [Total Number of Picks Per Order]
FROM erp.OrderHed AS OH

From
> ...

where
> ...

group by
> ...
CASE 
WHEN OH.CreditOverride = 1 THEN 'n/a'

WHEN OH.OrderHeld = 1 AND C.CreditHold = 0 AND C.AgingCreditHold = 0 AND OH.CreditOverride = 0 THEN 'HeldOrder'

WHEN C.CreditHold = 1 AND OH.OrderHeld = 0 AND C.AgingCreditHold = 0 AND OH.CreditOverride = 0 THEN 'CrHold'

WHEN C.AgingCreditHold = 1 AND C.CreditHold = 0 AND OH.OrderHeld = 0 AND OH.CreditOverride = 0 THEN 'AgingHold'

WHEN OH.OrderHeld = 1 AND C.CreditHold = 1 AND C.AgingCreditHold = 0 AND OH.CreditOverride = 0 THEN 'HeldOrder_CrHold'

WHEN OH.OrderHeld = 1 AND C.CreditHold = 0 AND C.AgingCreditHold = 1 AND OH.CreditOverride = 0 THEN 'HeldOrder_AgingHold'

WHEN C.CreditHold = 1 AND OH.OrderHeld = 0 AND C.AgingCreditHold = 1 AND OH.CreditOverride = 0 THEN 'CrHold_AgingHold'
ELSE 'n/a'
```

Sorry, Im SQL beginner, does anyone knows how I have to write the group by line correctly?

Comment: The `case` expression in the `group by` clause needs an `end` too.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? ANSI SQL doesn't allow case expressions in the GROUP BY clause.